# Pyqt5 Change styles of spesific lines in QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making a dictionary style program with pyqt5.

When you select the words, the explanation appears in QTextBrowser.

What I want is for the text on the first line of the QTextBrowser to be different from the style of the other lines.

I tried a few solutions on my own, but I couldn't, my code puts all lines in the QTextBrowser in the same style.

```
    def settextfont(self):
        font = self.font()
        font.setFamily(u"MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setPixelSize(14)
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setTextColor(QColor('#434343'))
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setFont(font)
```

The result my code does:

[image]

What I want should be:

[image]

I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: You can put HTML tags in the text.

Comment: @LeopardShark 
How can I do it please can you help me?

Comment: @aabb QTextBrowser inherits from QTextEdit (always check the documentation of inherited classes). Use [`setHtml()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html#unknownOptionNames).

Comment: @aabb You just have to modify the string you pass into `setText`, e.g. by surrounding the heading with an `<h1>` or `<h2>` tag.